# Raise a power series to a fractional exponent?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, exponentiation

In showing that $\log^\alpha{(1+x)}$ is $O((x)^\alpha)$ at $1$, for $\alpha>0$, one can note that

$$\left ( \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{x} \right )^\alpha \overset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} \left ( 1\right )^\alpha = 1.$$

So we know that $$\log^\alpha{(1+x)}= (x)^\alpha + o((x)^\alpha).$$

But how would I find $\beta > \alpha$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\log^\alpha{(1+x)}= (x)^\alpha + c(x)^\beta + o((x)^\beta)?$$

I'd like to raise the power series to an exponent:

$$\log^\alpha(1+x) = \left ( x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 + \dotsb \right) ^ \alpha = \,\,\,??$$

Is there a version of the multinomial theorem I need to use here? [This](http://fractional-calculus.com/multinomial_theorem.pdf#page=8) page I found gives me a formula for a multinomial when the first term is larger than the sums of the rest of the terms, but I don't think I want to use that...

Comment: You may write $(x+O(x^2))^\alpha$ as $x^\alpha(1+O(x))^\alpha$ and apply binomial expansion to $(1+t)^\alpha$ for $t$ small.

Comment: Definitely the latter...let me fix that

Comment: Is there a general method when one has more than two terms?

Comment: I am not clear how general for what expansion you need. Could you be more specific?

Comment: The binomial expansion of $(1+O(x))^\alpha$ gets us up to $O(x)$, and when multiplied by $x^\alpha$, we get $O(x^{\alpha + 1})$. Is there any way to find $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\log^{\alpha}{(1+ x)}=x^{\alpha} + c x^{\alpha + 1} + o(x^{\alpha+1})$?

Comment: Binomial expansion can give you as precise as you wish. For example,  up to $t^2$ term,  $(1+t)^\alpha=1+\alpha t+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2}t^2+O(t^3)$.  For $t=O(x)$, you will get $1+\alpha O(x)$; for $t=ax+o(x)$, you will get $1+a\alpha x+o(x)$; for $t=ax+bx^2+o(x^2)$, you will get $1+a\alpha x+(b\alpha+\frac{a^2\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2})x^2+o(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landscape has provided a very nice answer in the comments. I will summarize in this community wiki, hoping I am getting it right:

Given a power series to a (possibly fractional) exponent $\alpha > 0$, say the one in the original question:

$$ \left ( x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 + \dotsb \right) ^ \alpha,$$

one can factor out the $x$ term, and truncate at whatever term one desires

$$ x^\alpha \left  ( 1 - x/2 + x^2/3 + o(x^2) \right) ^ \alpha$$

and then apply the generalized binomial theorem

$$= x^\alpha \left  ( 1 + \alpha\cdot[- x/2 + x^2/3 + o(x^2) ] + \frac {\alpha (\alpha - 1) } {2} [ - x/2 + x^2/3 + o(x^2)  ]^2 \\
+ o( [ - x/2 + x^2/3 + o(x^2) ]^2)  \right)  \\
= x^\alpha - \frac {\alpha} {2} x^{\alpha + 1} + \left ( \frac {\alpha} {3} + \frac {\alpha(\alpha-1)} {8}  \right )x^{\alpha + 2} + o(x^{\alpha  + 2}).$$